# Build a pipeline in azure data factory to load Excel files, format content, transform in csv and send to azure sql DB

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks

I'm approaching to Azure environment and watching tutorials/reading documents, but I'm trying to figure out how to setup a flow that enables the process that I will describe hereunder. The starting point are reports in .xlsx format produced monthly by Mktg Dept: the requirements are to bring them in Azure SQL DB so that data can be stored and analysed. Sofar I managed to put those files (previously manually converted in .csv format) in a BLOB storage and build an ADF pipeline that copy each file in a table on the SQL DB.
The problem is that as far as I understood with ADF it's not possible to directly manage xlsx files, and I'm wondering how to set up an automated procedure that enables the conversion from .xlsx to .csv and save them on BLOB storage. I was thinking about adding to the pipeline a python script/Databricks notebook to convert format, but I'm not sure this could be the best solution. Any hint/reference to existing tutorial or resources would be very appreciated

Comment: Databricks can be pricy can you not manipulate the files before they go into blob storage? See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271088/execute-python-scripts-in-azure-datafactory

Answer (score 0):

I found a [tutorial](https://visualbi.com/blogs/microsoft/azure/consuming-excel-files-azure-data-factory/) which uses Logic Apps to do the conversion.

Datanovice indirectly suggested using a Custom activity to run either a [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) or [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory) application to do the conversion for you.

The least expensive solution would be to do the conversion before uploading to blob, like Datanovice said.

Comment: Hi, thank you, unfortunately the requirement is to do the conversion "in cloud". With LogicApp is possible but the file I have to convert has roughly 300 columns, as far as I saw there is a 100 columns limit on Logic App. At the end I did the conversion using a script on Databricks